# Showing definition list , dt, & dd on the same line

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-views

I want to show a few rows of data on a Details page, which each have a title and data on the same row. The data is showing fine, but since my titles are a little long, it is not fitting on the same line. It extends to the next line. For example, I want the title "**Speaker's Interaction with Audience**" to show in one line/row, instead of "**with Audience**" showing up on a new line under the first half of the title. I have been playing around for a while, but nothing seems to work.

[image: Details page picture]

This is how I have my style in the View

```
<style>
    dl {
        width: 395px;
        font-size: 15px
    }

    dd, dt {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    dt {
        float: left;
        padding-right: 5px;
        font-weight: bolder;
    }

    dt {
        clear: left;
    }

    dt, dd {
        min-height: 1.5em;
    }
</style>
```

And the structure of my code is like this

```
<div>
    <h4>IndividualSessionEvaluation</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OnScreenPresentation)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OnScreenPresentation)
        </dd>   

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SpeakersSubjectKnowledge)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SpeakersSubjectKnowledge)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SpeakersInteractionwithAudience)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SpeakersInteractionwithAudience)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<hr>` tag has no closing slash.

Comment: `<hr/>` isn't this opening and closing for the hr tag?

Comment: No. The `<hr>` tag is self closing and has no ending slash: https://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element

Answer (score 1):

Please use the Bootstrap column combination as follows

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <!-- Data -->
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <!-- Value -->
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Where am I supposed to put these column combinations in the View? I just have one div with a `<dl>` and several `<dt>` and `<dd>` inside of it.

Comment: Hi, can you please post a sample of your code structure?? Thank you.

Comment: @AlexisToby I have edited my post and posted a sample of my code structure that I have in my Details View page.

Comment: Why should he use bootstrap when you can do it on your own with CSS?